# “Ever” vs “Always”

Tags: adverbs

I have read that *always* is more used in American English, while *ever* is more used in British English. In this context, which of the following is correct:

> This always increasing interest brought. . . .

or

> This ever increasing interest brought. . . .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don’t know where you read that myth about *ever* and *always*, but it is not true.

Furthermore, neither of your two examples is correct.  One should instead write that this way, with a hyphen:

> This ever-increasing interest brought. . . .

Comment: is the hyphen (-) so important ?

Comment: @yes123 It is not a dash — it is a hyphen. And yes, it is “so” important.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is there a general rule for choosing always vs ever ?

Comment: @yes123 I don’t think there are many compounds that begin with *always-*; the only one I can think of is an ***always-on* switch**. For modifying *-ing* words, you really always want to use *ever*, as in *everlasting, ever-changing, ever-living*, etc.

Comment: The original sense of _ever_ (i.e, '*anywhen') is now strictly a [Negative Polarity Item](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/NPIs.pdf), so outside the scope of a negative trigger, _ever_ can only appear be a prefix in modern English. Most of these compounds are frozen from earlier, non-NPI, uses of _ever_.

Comment: _Man's real life is happy, chiefly because he 
is ever expecting that it soon will be so._ -  Edgar Allan Poe - when does modern English begin? Is that as distinct from Modern English?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth He means the kind of “stuff” that teenagers use in tweets, not actual literature.

Comment: @tchrist: Ever-tweeting; never meeting ... I'm fairly sure Tolkien  uses _ever_ in a non-negative construction. And tweeters might use _ever yours_. These usages do have an antique feel about them, though.